# Facebook Graph: Find Nearby Friends' Checkins

Tags: facebook, location, checkin

I want to use FB Graph API to find friends nearby within a certain time window and lat/lon/distance

This request (below) will return friends who have checked in within a time (since yesterday), but I can't seem to get the lat/lon/distance piece to work.  (I do have the correct token working fine)

https://graph.facebook.com/search?since=yesterday&type=checkin&center=34.06624,-118.41298&distance=10000

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using graph api explorer. It is easier to get tokens and find solutions.

Maybe this will help? You can get all checkins and then find those you need in your app. (You will need friends_status permission)
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Ffriends%2F%3Ffields%3Dcheckins

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I have never been able to get checkins via graph api. Always get back an empty array. I finally used FQL to do something similar to what you need. see if this question and answer helps you:
[how to find friend's past checkins near a location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904706/how-to-find-friends-past-checkins-near-a-location)